# Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:(

Tags: oracle, plsql

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq92h.jpg)

I was running a small code to learn the plsql and then error show this error

Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following: "("

What should i do? Should change " " of it

Comment: Please put the information in your linked screenshot directly into your question.  The link you provided could break at any time.

Answer (score 2):

`sum` is a name which is reserved for built-in function; don't name your variables like that, use something else (such as `l_sum` in my example):

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    a number(5);
  3    b number(5);
  4    l_sum number(5);
  5  begin
  6    a := 5;
  7    b := 5;
  8    l_sum := a + b;
  9    dbms_output.put_line('Sum is ' || l_sum);
 10  end;
 11  /
Sum is 10

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```